# AFNetworking Certificate Error

Tags: objective-c, ios, certificate, client-server, afnetworking

I am very new to Client/Server programming and networking in general. I am trying to connect to a server with my app using `AFNetworking`. It is throwing an error:

```
the certificate for this server is invalid....
```

How do I get `AFNetworking` framework to ignore this error and go ahead and load the data?

I am basically using the `AFNetworking` example on Twitter as a springboard to integrate it into my application.

Comment: Do you connect to a https website? Be better give some code

Comment: Yes it is HTTPS. I use the same code in the AFNetworking example. Sorry, I am not on my Mac. It doesn't execute much code besides getting path and on success load the requests on failure show the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the server in question have a self-signed SSL certificate by any chance?

If so, then you may find some useful information here:

- [AFNetworking issue
  #45](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/45)
- [AFNetworking issue
  #189](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/189)

The suggested approach is to define `_AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_` in which cae you may have some success allowing AFNetworking to accept invalid SSL certificates.  My experience has been hit or miss with this and the various other suggested ways of dealing with this - which often involve crashing on `com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader` in a background thread.

Comment: Hello Alan,
Thanks for the advice. I actually just installed the certificate on the phone so I could bypass the error all together.

Thanks!
Alan